# How to answer "why scala provides `object` keyword"?

Tags: scala, object, module

Someone asked me: Why scala provides `object` keyword?

I answer that with `object` we can:

1. create single instance on the language level
2. create new instance of other types as factories
3. combine different traits

But he said "These are what object can do, but not why".

What should I answer this question?

(I just read some articles about `object`, can I answer: Because scala want to support `module` on language level? )

Answer (score 1):

`object` is there to avoid `static` members. Scala was designed as a pure object oriented language, and `static` just isn't object oriented. `static` also makes code harder to understand as you mix code that just doesn't belong together conceptually. In general, separating static and instance members is a good idea.

Also `object` reduces boilerplate by implementing the singleton pattern for you and makes useless types less present.

Just compare:

```
class SomeGlobalService {
   private SomeGlobalService instance = null

   private SomeGlobalService() {
     <constructor code>
   }

   public static SomeGlobalService getInstance() {
     if (instance == null) 
       instance = new SomeGlobalService
     return instance
   }

   <members>
}

SomeGlobalService.getInstance().<someMember>
```

To

```
object SomeGlobalService {
  <constructor code>
  <members>
}

SomeGlobalService.<someMember>
```

In the first example the package is polluted by the useless class `SomeGlobalService` which you most defenetely will never use directly. In scala the type is less visible as it is `SomeGlobalService.type`.

Comment: Isn't a static variable no object?

Comment: a static constant is indeed an object, but it is at the wrong place. why would you put a static constant pointing to an instance of a class into the definition of a class? that is like spreading a bowl of potato salad on a recipe for potato salad. it does not belong together conceptually!